# Exibindo formulários através do Select com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, html5

Tenho um campo select  para o usuário escolher qual formulário deseja cadastrar os dados! ( 2 formulários a serem exibidos).
Ao selecionar a primeira opção no select, estou utilizando Jquery hide() e show() para exibir os formulários escolhidos.

Os formulários possuem um campo select que retorna dados do BD para o usuário escolher a opção!

Sendo que os dois formulários são os mesmos, gostaria de retornar duas consultas do banco de dados no mesmo formulário quando o usuário mudar a opção
no select!
Obs: estou desenvolvendo este formulário em PHP MySQL!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Mateus! Sim ja criei algo que retorne a consulta do banco de dados! E eu não quero que ninguém faça o código! Estou apenas pedindo uma ajuda! Agora se for pra criticar NÃO ajude por favor!

Comment: Você pode agregar à sua pergunta o código fonte que está utilizando para melhorar o nosso entendimento.

Comment: Quando você escolher uma opção, deseja realizar duas consultas?

Comment: @André Filipe,  ao selecionar o formulario 1 no select fará uma consulta, e ao selecionar o formulário 2 fará outra consulta! Irei editar a pergunta e colocarei um trecho do código para facilitar o entendimento de vcs!